# Powershell Progress Counter Scope Issue - Remote Session resetting progress tracker

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to track progress and I think it's a scope issue. The two functions are located in Functions.ps1 and are called from another script main.ps1. The progress is tracked fine until it gets the the invoke-command in Function 1. Why is the remote session resetting progress tracker? Here is what the code  and output look like:

main.ps1

```
. "C:\Functions.ps1" #dot source so functions available
$steps = 10
Write-ProgressHelper -stepTotal $steps -Status "reset"
```

Functions.ps1

```
Function Write-ProgressHelper {
    param (
        [int]$stepTotal,
        [string]$Status
    )
   Switch ($Status)
   {
    "run" {
        $global:Counter++
        Write-Host "$Counter"
        Write-Progress -Activity "STIG" -PercentComplete (($Counter / $stepTotal) * 100)
     }
    "reset" {
        $Counter = 0
        Write-Host "Counter Reset"
    }
  }
}

Function 1 {
    Write-Host "StepNumber:1"
    Write-ProgressHelper -stepTotal $steps -Status "run"

    #some code here
    Write-Host "StepNumber:2"
    $sysinfo = { 

        . "C:\Functions.ps1" #dot source so write-progresshelper is available within invoke-command

        #more code
        Write-Host "StepNumber:3"
        Write-ProgressHelper -stepTotal $using:steps -Status "run"
        Write-Host "StepNumber:4"
        #more code
        Write-ProgressHelper -stepTotal $using:steps -Status "run"

    }#end sysinfo
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Servers -ScriptBlock $sysinfo
    Write-Host "StepNumber:10"
    Write-ProgressHelper -stepTotal $using:steps -Status "run"
}#end Function 1
```

There are 10 Steps to track in Function 1 and then I output the $counter variable. Step 1,2, and 10 are within Function 1. Steps 3-9 are in invoke-command session. I tried declaring the counter as global and that didn't work (I had it declare with script scope in order for it to increment at all). Here is the output:

```
StepNumber:1
1
StepNumber:2
2
StepNumber:3
1
StepNumber:4
2
StepNumber:5
3
StepNumber:6
4
StepNumber:7
5
StepNumber:8
6
StepNumber:9
7
StepNumber:10
3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remote variables don't get saved back to local variables (See: [about_Remote_Variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_remote_variables?view=powershell-7#using-local-variables)). So even though you define `$counter` as a `$global` variable, it is only global within *that* PowerShell session. It is **not** available on the remote computer. When the `Invoke-Command` is called, a *new* PowerShell session is created on *that* computer, and `$counter` is reset to 0. It will increment and return. The existing value of the `$counter` variable on the local computer is retained, and continues on.

When we look at what the value of `$global:Counter` is, we have to realize that the variable is only available on the computer that the script is executing:

```
                 Local Computer    Server1            
                 ----------------- -------------------
                 $global:Counter   $global:Counter    
                 _________________ ___________________
StepNumber:1      1                (0)                
1
StepNumber:2      2                (0)                
2                       
    Invoke-Command -Computer Server1
                  |---------------->         
StepNumber:3     (2)                1                 
1
StepNumber:4     (2)                2                 
2
StepNumber:5     (2)                3                 
3
StepNumber:6     (2)                4                 
4
StepNumber:7     (2)                5                  
5
StepNumber:8     (2)                6                  
6
StepNumber:9     (2)                7                  
7
                  <-----------------|

StepNumber:10     3
3
```

See how the value of `$global:Counter` is incremented for step 1 and 2. When the `Invoke-Computer` is run, PowerShell creates a new PowerShell session on the remote computer, where the value of `$global:Counter` is 0. That is why you see the value apparently "reset". After steps 3-9 execute, the process returns to the local computer, where the value of `$global:Counter` is still 2. That is why you see for Step 10, it returns 3.

To have an effective counter, you will have to pass the counter value to the `Invoke-Command` as an `AgrumentList` and return the value back.

Comment: Just to clarify - I'm not counting within the invoke-command. I have `$using:steps` in order for `$stepTotal` to keep the total `$steps = 10` otherwise that gets lost. When `Write-ProgressHelper` is called, I am trying to get `$counter` incremented within the function. Shouldn't the function just increment locally whenever it is called? -Thanks

Comment: I understand the confusion, I reworked my answer to better clarify, please see edits above. Basically the term "locally" is within the PowerShell session on the computer that it is running on.